# How to remove the first "Visit Website X" option in Firefox address bar?

Tags: firefox, address-bar

How can I remove that first option there? It's useless, I want it to be gone completely. This used to be the default before, and it was added in some newer version I imagine.

Firefox 43.0b1 - Mac OSX Yosemite

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Greets from India.
I had the same problem, Google search landed me on this page.
Seeing that nobody answered, I took the matter into my own hands.

Type 
`about:config` into the awesome/location/address bar.
Accept the warning message.
Now look for this item:

> browser.urlbar.unifiedcomplete

Set `value` to `false`.

You're good to go.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Comment: lol i cant upvote you

Comment: This no-longer works in Firefox 48. Some background info [on bugzilla 12911750](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12911750), although no useful feedback from developers.